# efficient separating and combining vector by elements

Tags: opencv, c++11, qt5

I have a big std::vector containing data from images in rgb (uint8_t) format.
What I want is to separate the channels into new r,g and b vectors.
Afterwards doing some algorithms and recombine them into a rgb vector.

My problem is the rgb vector is continuous in the virtual memory so I could copy the data as a whole or accessing each element by itself, which is slow.
The same is true for the vice versa situation.

Is there an efficient way of accessing these elements?

Here a short example of my problem and what I have so far:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> rgb{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<uint8_t> r, g, b;
    for (auto i=0; i<rgb.size()/3; ++i)
    {
        r.push_back(rgb.at(i*3));
        g.push_back(rgb.at(i*3+1));
        b.push_back(rgb.at(i*3+2));
    }
    std::vector<uint8_t> rgb_reconst;
    rgb_reconst.resize(rgb.size());
    for (auto i=0; i<rgb.size()/3; ++i)
    {
        rgb_reconst.at(i*3) = r.at(i);
        rgb_reconst.at(i*3+1) = g.at(i);
        rgb_reconst.at(i*3+2) = b.at(i);
    }
}
```

I have access to Qt5 and OpenCV for this problem, however I would prefer a general C++11 solution as this can be interesting for other problems as well.

Comment: take a look at `reserve` method of vector to avoid reallocations

Comment: [`cv::split`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga8027f9deee1e42716be8039e5863fbd9), or [`cv::mixChannels`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) for more complex manipulations. However, if you don't want an OpenCV solution, I'd suggest you remove the tag. (Although it would kinda make sense to at least read the sources)

Comment: This really all depends on how your algorithms expect the data, and the access patters those algorithms use.  Copying the R, G, and B values into distinct arrays is requires additional space and time, but would be necessary if the algorithm expects the color data to be contiguous.  It might also be a performance benefit if the data locality is improved enough.  It might also allow running some of those algorithms in separate threads.